# Multiple inheritance ambiguous base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Consider the code

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived: public Base{};

struct A: public Base{};

struct B: public A, public Base{};

struct C: public A, public Derived{}; // why no ambiguity here?

int main() {}
```

The compiler (g++5.1) warns that

> warning: direct base `'Base'` inaccessible in `'B'` due to ambiguity `struct B: public A, public Base{};`

I understand this, `Base` is duplicated in `B`.

1. Why is there no warning for `C`? Doesn't `C` inherit from both `A` and `Derived`, which both inherit from `Base`?
2. Why adding `virtual`

   ```
   struct Derived: virtual Base{};
   ```

results now in both `B` and `C` emitting warnings, live on <kbd>[Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VWvtQX35GXQyezeq)</kbd>

> warning: direct base `'Base'` inaccessible in `'B'` due to ambiguity `struct B: public A, public Base{};`
>
> warning: direct base `'Base'` inaccessible in `'C'` due to ambiguity `struct C: public A, public Derived{};`

Comment: Search internet for "dreaded diamond inheritance".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know what the diamond problem is, and that's closely related to why `B` gives a warning. However what I don't understand is why `C` is OK.

Comment: I think it's just a case of gcc not detecting the ambiguity in `C` because `Base` *is* ambiguous in that case too. When you virtually derive from `Base` the most derived class (`C`) is responsible for calling the `Base` constructor, and so gcc starts detecting the ambiguity again.

Comment: @Praetorian it makes sense. clang++/vc++ don't spit any warnings at all, unless I make `struct Derived: public virtual Base`

Comment: I don't get the warning for `C` regardless of whether the inheritance is virtual or not. Which gcc version are you using?

Comment: @Brian gcc5.1, I'll put the code live in a sec.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/239a3b91c1e23eef

Comment: @Brian see the updated edit, http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VWvtQX35GXQyezeq

Comment: It could also be because with the original `C` I can address `Base`'s members by explicitly qualifying them. Say `Base` had a member function `void foo(){}`. Then I can say `C{}.A::foo(); C{}.Derived::foo();`, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to do that with `B`.

Comment: @Praetorian again a good point. Now I understand why Java decided against multiple inheritance :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `B`, it's impossible to refer to members of the `Base` subobject inherited directly. Consider:

```
struct Base {
    int x;
};

struct B: public A, public Base {
    void foo() {
        int& x1 = A::x; // OK
        int& x2 = x; // ambiguous
        // no way to refer to the x in the direct base
    }
};
```

In `C` this is not a problem. Both `x`'s can be referred to using qualified names:

```
struct C: public A, public Derived {
    void foo() {
        int& x1 = A::x; // OK
        int& x2 = Derived::x; // OK
    }
};
```

So the warning you get is one that only makes sense when a *direct* base is also inherited through another path.

For your second question, I couldn't reproduce the warning with `C` on Coliru with g++-5.1.

Answer (score 2):

There are no ways to access unambiguously to Base members in "B" whereas it's possible in "C", as illustrated in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    void print()
    {
        cout << "Base" << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base {};

struct A : public Base
{
    void print()
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A, public Base
{
    void print()
    {
        A::print();

        //error (ambiguous), no way to access to Base::print => warning
        //Base::print();
    }
};

struct C : public A, public Derived
{
    void print()
    {
        A::print();
        Derived::print(); // Not Ambiguous, it's the Base inherited by 'Derived' which is used.
        // Still an error but you can access print indirectly through "Derived" => no warning needed
        //Base::print();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B b;
    b.print();

    C c;
    c.print();

    return 0; 
}
```